# React component rendering multiple times, failing when reloading the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails (7.0.2) application and just installed React. I'm very new to react and can't seem to understand why it looks like my component is loading multiple times, the first time with an empty value for `props` and the second time with the correct values for `props`.

App.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import Customers from "./components/customers";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const API_URL = "http://localhost:3000/internal_api/v1/customers";

function getAPIData() {
  return axios.get(API_URL).then((response) => response.data);
}

function App() {
  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    getAPIData().then((items) => {
      if (mounted) {
        setCustomers(items);
      }
    });
    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, []);

  console.log('LOADED App.js');
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <Customers customers={customers} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and customers.js:

```
import React from "react";

function Customers(props) {
  console.log('LOADED customers.js');
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>These customers are from the API</h1>
      {props.customers.data.map((customer) => {
        return (
          <div key={customer.id}>
            <h2>{customer.id}</h2>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Customers;
```

When I remove this part of the code and reload the page, my `props` come through correctly when looking in console. Then, when I put the code back and save (without reloading), it displays correctly.

```
      {props.customers.data.map((customer) => {
        return (
          <div key={customer.id}>
            <h2>{customer.id}</h2>
          </div>
        );
```

However, as soon as I reload again, I get the same following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

It seems as though the first time everything renders, props is empty. Then the second time, it is full with the data. I checked my rails app and it only hits the API once. What am I doing wrong?

More log outputs:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**React component rendering multiple times?**

React will render fast before completing the request in use Effect

so in first render customers array will be empty

when request is fulfilled, you are changing state, So react will re-render the component

Only component that uses state reloads when the state is changed this is required else UI will not update

**failing when reloading the page? | Failed on Initial Load**

Since in Initial render customers will have no data customers.data will be undefined so it will not have map

to bypass this error use `props.customers?.data && props.customers.data?.map()` addding question mark means expression will be evaluated if not undefined

Source - [Optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: Do I always need to assume props may or may not be rendered any time I reload React? Do I need to use ? everywhere? Seems odd.

Comment: If you are getting data from somewhere then it is must,
If you have static data then no need
Also there may be chance that request fails or request data is empty so that's best practice to null check before accessing data from external sources
if it is null we can show there is no data

Comment: In the examples I'm following, "Setup A Ruby on Rails 7 API With React JS" on Youtube for example, the author does not use ? and it seems to work just fine for him.

Comment: Here is the source code for the video's project, this person does not use ?: https://github.com/Deanout/bookstore-react-video/blob/main/bookable/src/components/books.js

Comment: If you access props.customers there will be no problem because props.customers is empty array in given code he is acessing props.books so he is not getting error

Comment: If he tried to access props.books.data then it will be undefined and throw error

Comment: props.customers would be empty just like props.books though...I'm very confused what the difference is...

Comment: props.customers or props.books is [] and it have .map() method but if you see props.customers.data it is not [] , it is undefined so its has no .map() method

Comment: Add console.log(props.customers)  and console.log(props.customers.data) you will know difference

Comment: your state Initiation also wrong, It should be
const [customers, setCustomers] = useState({data:[]});
If you Intiate state like this then you need to check with question mark

Comment: I tried to set the state initiation as you said above and am getting the same error again. do I need to set the state like you mentioned in the above comment AND use the question mark?

Comment: post your code here